Can't use static_assert() in clang 18.1.7
For some reason I can't use static_assert() in clang-18.1.7
My clang is installed under conda environment and seems to be configured just fine.
(iree-build) $USER@$HOST:/localdisk/$USER|> clang -v
clang version 18.1.7 (https://github.com/conda-forge/clangdev-feedstock 1b91969d0c6b64ef555f9c04fc02d7758335f4b3)
Target: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /localdisk/$USER/opt/miniforge3/envs/iree-build/bin
Configuration file: /localdisk/$USER/opt/miniforge3/envs/iree-build/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-clang.cfg
Found candidate GCC installation: /localdisk/$USER/opt/miniforge3/envs/iree-build/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/13.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /localdisk/$USER/opt/miniforge3/envs/iree-build/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/13.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64

The code is trivial (sat.c):
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(int), "it works!");
    return 0;
}

But when I compile, I get this error:
(iree-build) $USER@$HOST:/localdisk/$USER|> clang -c sat.c --std=c11
sat.c:5:5: error: call to undeclared function 'static_assert'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    5 |     static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(int), "it works!");
      |     ^
1 error generated.

Why is that?

In C11, static_assert() is a macro, not a keyword. Therefore, it is most likely that the assert.h you are using does not contain the macro definition (not repro on godbolt). Perhaps the keyword _Static_assert() would compile.

But the proper fix should be to find out why the header is incorrect. Using the keyword is just a workaround.

@WeijunZhou You're right; of course, the use of keywords is a stopgap measure and does not provide a permanent solution.

@ramgorur try clang -c sat.c -std=c11 -H command (add -H option) to see which file you are referring to.

what @kakkoko said, the path should be x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/assert.h in your conda env.  I just tested in a fresh conda env with the exact same clang version and it works
